# Strange behavior of UICollectionView resulting in performance issues

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, frame

I have created a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and it was performing badly. I first thought it was a problem with my layout but after a lot of debugging it seems that the problem is with the `UICollectionView` itself. was able to recreate it in a very simple example:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private let numCells = 12
    private let numSections = 120

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 1)
        self.collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return numSections
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numCells
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(indexPath.section) / CGFloat(numSections), saturation: 1 - CGFloat(indexPath.item) / CGFloat(numCells), brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
        return cell
    }
}

public class MyLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    public override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        print("attributes \(rect)")
        return super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    }
}
```

As soon as i change the `contentInset.right > 0` it goes completely crazy calling `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` **twice** on every scroll update instead of once every time I come close to a rect that the `UICollectionView` does not know about yet. Why is this happening and is there a way to avoid those updates?

**Update:**

I did profile the example and as soon as `contentInset.right > 1` the device uses significantly more CPU time on 
`[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]` This seems to be an internal method though.

Comment: "As soon as i change the contentInset.right > 0 it goes completely crazy calling layoutAttributesForElementsInRect twice" Sorry, but why do you care? All you are doing is returning `super`; that is not going to cause any performance issues. It's great that you've provided this small example but I don't see how it recreates any problem. If you do have performance issues and you want to know where the bottleneck is, use Instruments; that's what it's for.

Comment: My custom Layout has ~200 loc but as I said the root cause of the bad performance seems to be the collectionView itself. My custom layout has nothing to do with it, except that it takes a little but not significantly longer to compile the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` 
I updated the answer to include the result from the profiler